# VerifyCsrfToken doesn't work in Laravel 9

Tags: php, csrf-token, laravel-9

I wanna check CSRF for a POST method in my website which I use Ajax request to handle it therefore, I added this meta tag:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Then I added this header into request:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

I wanted to test `VerifyCsrfToken` therefore, changed that meta tag's content with Dev-Tools inspect and surprisingly code insert's new record into database?

I thought probably forgot to edit anything else?

In fact, I don't get `CSRF token mismatch` error

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if it answers your question but if you are checking it by running Tests then For convenience, the CSRF middleware is **automatically disabled** for all routes **when running tests**.
[Click to see the Screenshot from the laravel docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpCJj.png)

Here's the link to docs => https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/csrf#csrf-excluding-uris